# Quasar build in history mode on apache server. But it only load index.html instead router defined component

Tags: apache, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

Quasar project work in dev mode. But after build using quasar build command. It only load index.html only.

Answer (score 0):

You need a file .htaccess (root of your index.html) with this inside :

```js
RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

read carefully for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`
ref. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html